# Pandas dataframe concat after reading large number of txt files using glob takes never ending time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are some 50k txt files which I am trying to read to pandas dataframe as per code below.
But the process is still running for 2 hrs. Is there any better way to speed up this?

```
folder_path = '/drive/My Drive/dataset/train'
file_list = glob.glob(folder_path + "/*.txt")


def read_clean_df(file_name) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df = pd.read_fwf(file_name, header=None)
    df = df.drop(df.index[19])    
    df = df.T           
    df.columns = df.iloc[0]
    df = df[1:]
    df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
    return df


train_df = read_clean_df(file_list[0])

for file_name in file_list[1:len(file_list)]:
    df = read_clean_df(file_name)
    train_df = pd.concat([train_df, df], axis=0)

train_df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
print(train_df.head(30))
```

Comment: `df = pd.concat(list(map(read_clean_df, list_files)))`

Answer (score 1):

Do the concatenation once, at the end:

```
dfs = []
for file_name in file_list:
    df = read_clean_df(file_name)
    dfs.append(df)
tran_df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

If that is not fast enough, use `datatable` which can do multithreaded IO reading of csv files:

```
df = dt.rbind(iread(file_list)).to_pandas()
```

Comment: the `1:` in `file_list[1:len(file_list)]` is probably no longer necessary?

Comment: @ignoring_gravity Correct, updated

Comment: @ignoring_gravity I added another example using `datatable` if you are interested, I've used it before and its really fast.

Comment: @TomMcLean the below concat operation is crashing the RAM --  train_df = pd.concat(dfs)
any other option to split and concatenate maybe?

Comment: @ggcoder Did you try datatable?

Comment: yes @TomMcLean , but i am getting this error for that... IOWarning: Could not read /drive/My Drive/dataset/train/19748.txt: Too many fields on line 12: expected 2 but more are present. <<Weather conditions                       Fog>>

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, repeatedly calling `concat` is slow, this is the reason `DataFrame.append` was deprecated

Instead, do

```py
dfs = []

for file_name in file_list:
    df = read_clean_df(file_name)
    dfs.append(df)

train_df = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: while doing concat "train_df = pd.concat(dfs) " , it is crashing my RAM

Comment: how big is the data? Might need something other than pandas I guess then